# how to use select * from table in SQL task to pass selected data to foreach loop

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have SQL task before the foreach loop like this [tutorials](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/4579/looping-through-variable-values-with-a-foreach-loop-container) in how to use foreachloop my question is can I use select * from table and store in user variable object type to use it in foreach loop

Comment: You need to use cursors

Comment: other thing cursors is rerecorded to use in ssis

Comment: Yes you can. That tutorial shows you exactly how to do it. Why don't you try it and post any specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Example of cursor.

```
declare @ItemID nvarchar(50)
declare @ItemName nvarchar(50)
declare @itemList nvarchar(50)

declare dbc cursor
for select ItemID,ItemName,CPU from itemList

open dbc

FETCH NEXT FROM dbc into @ItemID,@ItemName,@itemList

while @@FetchStatus =0

begin

       -- write your code
         FETCH NEXT FROM dbc into @ItemID,@ItemName,@itemList

end

close dbc
deallocate dbc
```